# Library not loaded ... code signing blocked on macos 10.15.4

Tags: code-signing, mmap, macos-catalina, dyld

I am getting an error when running my app on macos 10.15.4

The error is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Frameworks/libQt5Solutions_SingleApplication-head.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/raulsanchez/Documents/workspace/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/raulsanchez/Documents/workspace/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQt5Solutions_SingleApplication-head.1.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/Users/raulsanchez/Documents/workspace/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQt5Solutions_SingleApplication-head.1.dylib'
/Users/raulsanchez/Documents/workspace/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQt5Solutions_SingleApplication-head.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
zsh: abort
```

I have deleted and reinstalled my certificate but still same error.

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the similar issue after Xcode has been updated (in my case to 11.4.1)
Nothing helped: neither re-creating certificates  nor updating entitlements nor rebooting nor changing trust level for certificates nor upgrading Xcode.

I **solved** it temporary **by downgrading my Xcode** (Xcode_11.3.1)

I noticed that libraries that fails to be loaded has no LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX/sdk. It is set 'n/a'. Then I found this issue https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83100
It helped!

In a few words:

```
otool -l myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libMyVnaApi_x64.0.dylib  | grep -B1 -A3 LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
Load command 8
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.13
      sdk n/a
```

If there is no sdk then hardened runtime library validation fails.

After I added linker flag and rebuilt

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
```

**Issue is solved**: sdk is set properly. Signed hardened application works

```
   otool -l myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libMyVnaApi_x64.0.dylib  | grep -B1 -A3 LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
Load command 8
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.13
      sdk 10.15.4
```

Comment: I was able to fix the issue adding entitlements but I will test your solution. It seems safer! Thanks

Comment: Could you please share which entitlement helped you?

Comment: com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation. But in any case maybe your solution is better since as my understanding entitlements can lead into security problems